# Publish test results from pod inside kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, pipeline, azure-pipelines

I have a full website based on kubernetes cluster.
I'm currently running an integration tests from the vsts build CI/CD pipeline as pod inside the cluster so the test is checking the real system.
For the moment, the final step for the test is to generate a file: 'result.xml'
Is there any way that it could publish the result's file content back to vsts build?
if not, do you have some kind of other strategy to suggest me? it will be great.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is Publish Test Result step/task (Test catalog) that can be used to publish test result to VSTS/TFS.

On the other hand, this article may benefit you: [Continuous Delivery to Kubernetes clusters using VSTS](https://github.com/dtzar/blog/tree/master/CD-Kubernetes-VSTS)